# Could not access file: Could not access file: Could not access file: PHP Mailer issue

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Code is working fine without attachments. and attachment code is working fine on another page anybody can help to solve this?
<?php

```
require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port     = 465;  
$mail->Username = "info@guildsconnect.org";
$mail->Password = "Guildsconnect";
$mail->Host     = "webs10rdns1.websouls.net";
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->SetFrom($contact_email, $contact_name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($contact_email, $contact_name);
$mail->AddAddress("hashimbhatti906@gmail.com"); 
$mail->Subject = $sub1;
$mail->WordWrap   = 80;
$mail->MsgHTML($emailbodyis);

foreach ($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] as $k => $v) {
    $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$k], $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$k] );
}

$mail->IsHTML(true);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $_SESSION["error"] = "Problem in Sending Mail.";
} else {
    $_SESSION["success"] = "Mail Sent Successfully.";
}   

?>
```

Comment: What does your directory look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you're using a very old and unsupported version of PHPMailer, so [upgrade](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/). It also looks like you have based your code on a very old example.

You are not handling the file upload safely, not validating the uploaded file before trying to use it, as per [the PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

PHPMailer provides [an example that shows how to handle and upload and attach it correctly](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). The key parts are to use [`move_uploaded_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to validate the upload before using it, and not to trust the supplied filename. To paraphrase the example:

```php
    //Extract an extension from the provided filename
    $ext = PHPMailer::mb_pathinfo($_FILES['userfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    //Define a safe location to move the uploaded file to, preserving the extension
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['attachment']['name'])) . '.' . $ext;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        //Now create a message
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
...
        //Attach the uploaded file
        if (!$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file')) {
            $msg .= 'Failed to attach file ' . $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
        }
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $msg .= 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            $msg .= 'Message sent!';
        }
    } else {
        $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
```

You don't need to set `Mailer` yourself; it's already done for you by `isSMTP()`.

Comment: Ok Dear Thank You